# Control visible depending on what exists in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, data-binding

what I need help with is: I have a field in the database (MySql) called `seq_orcamento` that allow null, when it is not null I need that a LinkButton inside a FormView(that has as datasource a SqlDataSource) to be visible. What I did in my select command is

```
SELECT CASE seq_orcamento WHEN NOT NULL THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS idc_seq FROM log_transacao
```

It is working fine, but is there a way to do some kind of bind that when `idc_seq = 1` the LinkButton becomes visible?

I have no problem using code-behind if any of it is necessary, I'm using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it: in the Visible propertie I added the code

```
Visible='<%# Eval("idc_seq") == "1" ? true : false %>'
```

Don't know if it works yet because I need to use it only when the site is published, I will try it later

Comment: My guess is this would probably work although I usually work in vb.Net so I don't have the luxury of the `?` operator.  Be careful that `Eval("idc_seq")` does not evaluate to null in some circumstances, although based on your query it looks like it's always going to be '1' or '0'.  If necessary you can use a code-behind function that takes `Eval("idc_seq")` as `object`, do some null checking, and returns `string`.

Comment: But how will the string this function return be taken as something the LinkButton can interpret as `visible = true` or `visible = false`?

Comment: If you do your Binding Expression as you typed it above, for instance `Visible='<%# DetermineVisible(Eval("idc_seq") %>'`, the string result of `DetermineVisible()` will be assigned to the Visible property just as if you manually typed it into your markup (so you will want to return 'true' or 'false')

Comment: Thanks, if the way I did it doesn't work I will try what you said, one question though: how in the code-behind can I treat the `Eval("idc_seq")`? I never used Eval or Bind in the code-behind. How the Eval function knows from wich SqlDataSource I want to do the Eval?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataBound event of FromView Control

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataRowView dataRow = ((DataRowView)FormView1.DataItem);
       LinkButton lb= (LinkButton )FormView1.FindControl("LinkButton ");

       if (Convert.ToBool(DataBinder.Eval(formview.DataItem, "idc_seq") ) )
        { lb.visible=true;     }
       else{lb.visible=false;}

     }
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this, this doesn't look like the ideal way to do it